# HTML + CSS dropdown menu: how to add a button between each first-level link without breaking the alignment?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I succeeded in creating my navigation menu by following [this tutorial](http://html.com/anchors-links/menus/#Adding_Drop-Down_Links_to_a_Horizontal_Navbar).

CSS code:

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #F2C777;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #7C785B;
}

li a:hover {
    background-color: #EC8C65;
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropbutton:hover .droplinks{
    /*Cause the div to be displayed only when a website visitor hovers their mouse over the list item containing the div*/
    display: block;
} 

.droplinks {
    /*Break the div out of the layout flow of the list*/
    position: absolute;
    /*Give the div a background color and width*/
    background-color: #F2D299;
    min-width: 140px;
    /*Hide the div from view*/
    display: none;
}

.droplinks a {
    /*Match the padding applied to the other menu items*/
    padding: 10px;
    /*For the links to each fill a complete row in the containing div*/
    display: block;
}
```

HTML code:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">Home</a></li>     
        <!--Add a class to the list item with the drop menu-->
        <li class="dropbutton"><a href="">Products</a>
            <!--Add dropdown menu links before closing li tag-->
            <div class="droplinks">
                <a href="">Widgets</a>
                <a href="">Cogs</a>
                <a href="">Gears</a>
            </div>
        </li>
        <!--Add a class to the list item with the drop menu-->
        <li class="dropbutton"><a href="">Services</a>
            <!--Add dropdown menu links before closing li tag-->
            <div class="droplinks">
                <a href="">Handshakes</a>
                <a href="">Winks</a>
                <a href="">Smiles</a>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Shop</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>   
    </ul>
</nav>
```

However, when I go to my website with a smartphone, I can't go over a first-level link without clicking on it. Therefore, there is no way of clicking on a link inside a drop-down menu. That's why I'd like to add a button or a small area between each first-level link that behaves like such a link on "hover" but on which I can click without navigating to another page.

I cannot put this button into the link. I tried to put it just after the a closing tag but it breaks the alignment. Then, I tried to modify the "display" attribute of the links inside the "dropbutton" class and to use a "div" tag to make my button but it didn't solve my problem.

How can I put a button between each first-level link into my multi-level drop-down menu by keeping all first-level links and those buttons horizontally aligned and in a single line when there is enough room?

It's a bit similar to the navigation bar of [this website](http://cooperativa.cat) except that the sub-link indicator "»" mustn't be inside the first-level link.

N.B: Please do **NOT** provide a solution using JQuery, I know this library and this isn't what I'm looking for.

[JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/mq52w27w/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated your code on jsfiddle with pure CSS solution, using pseudoelement :after, with unicode character as an arrow, indicationg the dropdown menu. I display the dropdown using :focus selector(when u touch the arrow on mobile device the :focus is fired).

```
.dropbutton:after {
    content:"\25BC";
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:middle;
    margin:0 15px 0 5px;
}
.dropbutton:after:focus > .droplinks {
    display:block;
}
```

[jsFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/mq52w27w/24/)

Comment: I found another solution in the meantime, I added .dropbutton a {
    display: inline-block;
} into my CSS but yours seems to be easier to understand for the end user and it works better on mobile devices. I'm going to do some tests and I'll probably accept it :) Thanks a lot.

Comment: Great job. It works very well, I gave it a try on my Samsung Galaxy S3 (i9305) 4G with Firefox. I spent a lot of time in testing because of my mistake on an ID selector. I was a bit disappointed by the background color of the drop links which shouldn't be the same than the background color of the links in the first level, I'll try to fix that by myself.

Answer (score 0):

Does clicking the first level link actually take you somewhere meaningful on your site? On the example site, it just redirects to a page with the menu in it.

I think I would disable that behavior and write the code so that, in addition to hovering, clicking the first level link, opens the menu, but doesn't redirect.

This would make it so on a desktop, clicking is basically useless, but on a smartphone, it would allow you to open the menu.

I would have just made this a comment, but I do not have the ability to comment yet....

Comment: In my site, yes, the first level link takes me somewhere meaningful, that's why I'd like to keep this link and add another button.